# swap graphic objects inside a spark ItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, itemrenderer

I'm writing a s:ItemRenderer to render some simple graphical components in my app. Each element can have multiple shapes that can be selected by the user, i.e. a certain element can be a square, or a circle, or a star, or whatever else.

The simplest way I could think for doing this was to include all possible shapes in a s:Group and then manage their visible tag depending on what shape the user has selected. Is there a better way to do that?

Also, if I encapsulate the group in a separate MXML component, how do I propagate the state of the itemRenderer (say "hovered") down to the MXML component that manages the shapes?

thank you!

f

---

Edited: here's a code snippet to better explain the situation. Let's say you want to display three types of objects alternatively - the IR below with an AS snippet that turns visible to false for 2 out of the 3 objects definitely does the trick, but seems so ugly to me. In the mean time I found setCurrentState(stateName:String, playTransition:Boolean=true) to propagate the state down, so that's solved.

```
<s:ItemRenderer>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="hovered" />
</s:states>
<s:Group width="100%">
    <s:Rect width="20" height="10" radiusX="3" radiusY="3">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="Black" weight="1" pixelHinting="true"/>
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="red" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Rect id="square" width="10" height="10" radiusX="3" radiusY="3">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="Black" weight="1" pixelHinting="true"/>
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="green"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Ellipse id="circle" visible="true" width="10" height="10">
        <s:stroke>               
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="Black" pixelHinting="true" weight="1"/>     
        </s:stroke>          
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color.normal="yellow" color.hovered="0xCEDBEF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Ellipse>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Are each of these shapes loaded as an image? Are you drawing them dynamically through code? Do you have a code snippet that would give us a better idea of what you've got already?

Comment: drawing them dynamically through code - will edit post in a sec to add code. thx. f

Comment: Are these item renderer really data driven?

Comment: sorry - they are (this is just a simple mock example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The simplest way I could think for
>   doing this was to include all possible
>   shapes in a s:Group and then manage
>   their visible tag depending on what
>   shape the user has selected. Is there
>   a better way to do that?

Yes. Item renderers need to be made as light weight as possible. Using the includeInLayout would be a bit better since it will only add what you need to the display list.

> Also, if I encapsulate the group in a
>   separate MXML component, how do I
>   propagate the state of the
>   itemRenderer (say "hovered") down to
>   the MXML component that manages the
>   shapes?

I'm not quite sure I understand the question. Item renderer are data driven, so their instances have no reliable state. Renderer instances may display any given data item at any given time. Any information passed to an item renderer should be passed down through it's data item or you will run into syncing errors in your display.

Comment: drkstr, thank you for your reply. From what I've read so far about spark ItemRenderers they definitely have a state and you can do all sorts of fun things with that... I'm wondering if maybe you're thinking about mx ItemRenderers? That would also explain the reference to includeInLayout, which I believe is also more of an mx deal? (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html)

Comment: Sorry, when I say state I mean like an internal data state, not the "skin state". You can certainly have skin states, although they are controlled by the parent component. However, item renderer instances are recycled so you cannot rely on any internal data state (unless that has changed, which I'm almost certain it has not). Also, inculdeInLayout is used quite extensively in the spark skins. In fact, I wasn't even aware of it until I started poking around in the spark skin source.

Comment: PS: Since the skin states are controlled by the parent data group, it should be safe to pass that info along using a simple state change such as: ``<foo:MyComponent currentState.hovered="hovered" />`` just make sure you are not relying on any local vars to drive that functionality.